# Where is android application installed in my sd card

Tags: android

I just want to view the files(especially the .png files) associated with one of the  application in my mobile. The application is actually installed(moved) in the SD card.

The issue is ..I could not find the application in the SD card. I am using a file browser called 'File Manager' to browse through the SD card. Can someone help me on this.

Answer (score 2):

It should be here:

```
/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/your_package_name/
```

Answer (score 0):

Some hardware implements the path to the external storage different.

```
/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/your_package_name/
/mnt/sdcard-ext/Android/data/your_package_name/
```

You may be able to get a better view of what is on the device by using the ADB Shell.  If you still have trouble at this point trying running grep or find from the shell.

**UPDATE**

Most of the time the files associates with your application are in the directory with your application.  The application is installed in /data/data/your.package.name/.  However you will need root access to get here if you are on a phone, I think the emulator lets you get here.  As far as external storage... yea its a pain, to much fragmentation in the market.  You have to programmatically check the location of the external storage.

Comment: Hi, Thanks. Have already tried this. But could not see the application installed in that location. Will probably try with ADB shell. Not sure why it is so difficult in Android to find the location of the installed application. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

On my device with Android 2.3.6 apps moved on the SD card are located into a directory named .android_secure as .asec files (see http://www.fileinfo.com/extension/asec).

They are not visible from the standard "Archive" browser which shows the hidden directory as empty.

The files are also encrypted so I guess no access to the images within is possible.