# Where are Android apps installed?

Tags: android, apk

What is the actual directory where. APKs are installed?  The only directory I could find that somewhat resembles this is

```
sdcard/Android/data/
```

but it doesn't contain all my apps.

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3002/where-in-the-file-system-are-applications-installed

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9533282/where-is-android-application-installed-in-my-sd-card

Comment: @t0mm13b sorry I posted in the wrong location.  Is there any way I can migrate it to [Android Enthusiasts](http://android.stackexchange.com)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends.

Beginning with API Level 8, you can allow your application to be installed on the external storage (for example, the device's SD card). This is an optional feature you can declare for your application with the android:installLocation manifest attribute. If you do not declare this attribute, your application will be installed on the internal storage only and it cannot be moved to the external storage.

Internal location is `/data/app/yourapplicationnname`.

Comment: Thanks, but on my device (Kindle Fire, no clue what API version) `/data/` is an empty folder. ???

Comment: Oh, nevermind the last comment.  I just read the first answer to the first comment [link](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3002/where-in-the-file-system-are-applications-installed/) above.  It states that you have to have a rooted device to view that folder.